# What is a KnownType in WCF

Tags: c#, wcf

i am learning wcf. so i encounter a wcf attribute called known type. here i got a piece of code which is not clear.

```
[DataContract]
   public class UserAccount {}

   [DataContract]
   public class Admin : UserAccount {}

   [DataContract]
   public class Guest : UserAccount {}

[DataContract]
  [ServiceKnownType(typeof(Admin))]
  [ServiceKnownType(typeof(Guest))]
  public class SecurityInfo
  {
          [DataMember]
          private UserAccount user;
  }
```

now the tutorial is saying that Above code will work fine, either we set SecurityInfo data member to Admin or Guest.But if KnownTypeAttribute for Admin and Guest are not provided, deserialization engine will not recognize Admin and Guest types and will cry.

what is relation ship between SecurityInfo and admin & guest class ?
i really do not understand what known type attribute is doing here. i am not familiar with known type attribute and do not know what it does and when to use it.

so i like to request please make me understand the known type attribute in such a way as a result i can understand it's use and what it is....so come with one easy sample code where i can understand what is known type attribute. thanks

Comment: Everything starts [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2455244/what-is-the-difference-in-wcf-when-using-knowntype-and-serviceknowntype)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

(those are over simplified explanations that illustrate the concepts, not the technical implementation in WCF).

When a message is sent over the network, using WCF for instance, it is serialized. In other words (most of the time), in text. Say XML. The XML sent by the client to the server describes the data and its structure.

```
<data>
  <SecurityInfo>
    <user type="UserAccount">(some further XML data here)</user>
  </SecurityInfo>
</data>
```

When this code is recieved, the WCF API parses the XML and tries to create C# objects you will be able to manipulate in your code. Here an instance of the `Securityinfo`class with a property of type `UserAccount`. But how does it know which class can be instanciated?

Obviously the `<user>` node holds the class name in its attributes. But what if the client sent a derivated instance like the `Admin` class? You would receive something like this:

```
<data>
  <SecurityInfo>
    <user type="Admin">(some further XML data here)</user>
  </SecurityInfo>
</data>
```

The `[KnownType]` attribute informs the WCF service that "it is ok" to receive this `Admin` type because it is a subclass of the awaited `UserAccount`type.

It is especially important when the `Admin` subclass has more properties, like a `public string AdminEmail { get;set; }`. This property will be sent by the client too. WCF server, when doing its parsing job server-side, is informed this additional property is valid since the `Admin` type is a valid `[KnownType]`.

Comment: my question is that we often work with base class with derived class in C# but we never inform that who is base of derived something. then why wcf can not parse....it should have that kind of intelligence.

Comment: r u trying to say that when we work with derived type then we need to use known type attribute....other wise not required. please come with example of all kind of situation where we need to use known type attribute. thanks

Comment: what y trying to say: u said :-  it is serialized. In other words (most of the time in SOA), in text. u said text and some time u said xml....not very clear.

Comment: @Mou you are right to ask this question. It would be technically possible to do so. But WCF is based on contracts. Those (XML) contracts do not mimic your whole object hierarchy by default. This is the same reason why you need to use `[DataContract]` and `[DataMember]` attributes. To dig furter look for "Serializer" in the MSDN documentation. Since you can change the (De)Serializer implementation, you need to split your object C# hierarchy from your contract definition.

Comment: @Mou most of the time in text: some times in bitstream (like for media, but a bit too specific for your case). And serializing in text could be in XML or JSon (the two main formats used on the internet)

Comment: just clarify that when we use known type attribute...for base class or drived class? in my exmaple i used base class...then is it require?

Comment: can u plzz come up with a neat example for known type attribute like when to use it thanks.

Comment: @Askolein in your example, would I be able to get `AdminEmail ` in my method in wcf which accepts `UserAccount` type . (given that I have decorated my data contract class with `[ServiceKnownType(typeof(Admin))]`  )

Answer (score 0):

A known type is used in WCF to alert the data contract serializer to a type that it will need to deal with that is not immediately obvious to the outer nodes of the service contract. For example, if you had a base type (in your case the UserAccount) the serializer needs to know about the 2 actual real types that the UserAccount could be: Admin or Guest. The known type is typically used for collections of polymorphic types in my experience.